# "EXE_BAD_ACCESS" in completion Handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, completionhandler

I am getting "EXE_BAD_ACCESS" But i dont know where i have done mistake
Please have a look on the code and let me know the mistake.

```
+ (void)showBounceAnimatedView:(UIView *)popUp completionBlock:(void (^)())completionMy {
 popUp.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.7, 0.7);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/1.5 animations:^{
    popUp.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
        popUp.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
           popUp.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            completionMy(); <-----------
        }];
    }];
}];
}
```

The arrow is showing where i am getting is error;

Comment: try : 
if(completionMy) {
      completionMy();
}